# What Double Colon does in RewriteCond?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?)/?(.*)::\2$
```

Looks like this operator is nowhere to find in any reference or manual. Where can I find it or anyone could explain what this operator does?

Comment: Can you send a full RewriteCond line that has a double colon?

Comment: Example added. I kind of know what it does, but I'm looking for some deeper insight or official document if it's available since I can't find it when googling.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
```

can also be written as (using `##` as fixed delimiter on either side of condition):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}##$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)##\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
```

**Explanation:**

- You could use `$1` captured from `RewriteRule` in your `RewriteCond` because `mod_rewrite` actually **processes a ruleset backwards**. It starts with the pattern in the `RewriteRule`, and if it matches, goes on to check the one or more `RewriteCond`.
- So as you can see in a `RewriteCond`, the LHS (left-hand side / test string) can use backreference variables e.g. `$1`, `$2` OR `%1`, `%2` etc but RHS (right-hand side) i.e. condition string **cannot use** these `$1`, `$2` OR `%1`, `%2` variables.
- Inside the RHS condition part only backreference we can use are **internal back-references** i.e. the groups we have captured in this condition itself. They are denoted by `\1`, `\2` etc.
- In your `RewriteCond` first captured group is `(.*?/)`. It will be represented by internal back-reference `\1`.
- As you can mark out that this rule is basically finding `RewriteBase` **dynamically** by comparing `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `$1`. An example of `%{REQUEST_URI}` will be `/directory/foobar.php` and example of `$1` for same example URI will be `foobar.php`. `^(.*?/)::(.*)\1$` is putting the difference in 1st captured group `%1` or `\1`. Here it will populate `%1` or `\1` with the value `/directory/` which is used later in setting up env variable `%{ENV:BASE}` i.e. `E=BASE:%1`.

Comment: The 5th bullet point puzzles me a little. How this work:  ^(.*?/)::(.*)\1$ is putting the difference in 1st captured group %1 or \1?

Comment: From my understanding, :: operator is simply delimiter, How can a delimiter capture the difference between groups?

Comment: And for this one, (.*?/), what's the difference with (/), using /directory/foobar.php as an example. the 1st group captured would be both (/), but when I use ^(/)(.*)::\2$, it's not working

Comment: For the given examples `%{REQUEST_URI}::$1` expression makes it `/directory/foobar.php::foobar.php` on LHS. On RHS we have  regex as`^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$` will place `/directory/` in `%1` and `.*` before `::` makes it capture `foobar.php` in `%2`. After `::` we have back-reference to `\2` which is  `foobar.php`. [Also check this regex demo to understand it better](https://regex101.com/r/zM1aT5/1)

Comment: Good explanation! Thanks.

Comment: I have one minor finding. RHS can also be written as ^(.*/)(.*)::\2$, which yields exact result but one char shorter. Is there any situation you can think of this one doesn't work?

Comment: Yes you're right `^(.*/)(.*)::\2$` can also be used.

Comment: I still don't get it. How can `/directory/foobar.php` be `/directory/foobar.php::foobar.php` on LHS ? Logs show clearly:`RewriteCond: input='/directory/foobar.php::/directory/foobar.php' pattern='^(.*?/)(.*)::\\2$' => not-matched` so I'm still trying to figure out a case where this rule would actually match anything

Comment: If `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `$1` are both `/directory/foobar.php` then `%{ENV:BASE}` would be just `/`. If .htacces is in `/directory` then `%{ENV:BASE}` would be `/directory/`.