# Using mod_rewrite with variables (for proxying in htaccess)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

While there are a lot of questions dealing with this topic, I still cannot wrap my head around this particular case... So here is a generic example, that should illustrate my problem:

So, I have an Apache server, that does some proxying. My "application" is in `htdocs/mydir`, which is where the `.htaccess` is, as well.

I have the following rule in the `.htaccess`, that works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydir/pics/first(/.*)? [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydir/pics/second(/.*)? [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydir/pics/third(/.*)?
RewriteRule ^pics/(.*)$ http://192.168.7.13:5055/$1 [P,L]
```

So, when I trigger the address `http://localhost/mydir/pics/first/IMG12.jpg` in my browser, Apache gets this request proxied/forwarded to `http://192.168.7.13:5055/IMG12.jpg`, which is what I'd want in this case. (Note that there could be 3rd level subdirectories other than "first", "second" or "third", which I would not like processed as above).

Now, the thing is, that I have several "subdirectories" under `mydir` that I'd like to handle besides `pics` - say, also `videos`, `drawings`, `songs` etc. So, I'd like to avoid repeating all of the above rules for each and every subdirectory, and use some kind of a variable instead, that will be extracted from the request.

I'm aware that I can capture the subdirectory portion in an environment variable - this rule also works for me, and sets the SUBDIR variable to whatever the right subdirectory is in the request:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydir/(pics|videos|drawings|songs)(?:/.*)?
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDIR:%1]
```

Now, the problem is - how could I use this variable as a stand-in for the verbatim subdirectory in the proxying RewriteRule? As noted in other questions like [What Double Colon does in RewriteCond?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605218/what-double-colon-does-in-rewritecond) , [%N backreference inside RewriteCond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970170/n-backreference-inside-rewritecond) - this does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydir/(pics|videos|drawings|songs)(?:/.*)?
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDIR:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydir/%{SUBDIR}/first(/.*)? [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydir/%{SUBDIR}/second(/.*)? [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydir/%{SUBDIR}/third(/.*)?
RewriteRule ^%{SUBDIR}/(.*)$ http://192.168.7.13:5055/$1 [P,L]
```

... because of limitations of what can be used in left-hand-side vs. right-hand-side of RewriteRule vs RewriteCond (which I still cannot understand fully).

However, looking at this example - would it somehow be possible to rewrite the above, so a variable is used to extract the 2nd level subdirectory, and it is then used to match in the RewriteRule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I trigger the address `http://localhost/mydir/pics/first/IMG12.jpg`
> in my browser, Apache gets this request proxied/forwarded to
> `http://192.168.7.13:5055/IMG12.jpg`

To clarify, according to the directives you've posted, it would forward the request to `http://192.168.7.13:5055/first/IMG12.jpg`, not simply to `/IMG12.jpg`.

You could just do this in a single rule, the additional *conditions* would seem to be superfluous. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(pics|videos|drawings|songs)/(first|second|third)/(.*) http://192.168.7.13:5055/$2/$3 [P]
```

However, there is a potential issue with this as you are not currently passing the first directory through to the target. So, for instance, you couldn't have a file in the `pics` subdirectory the same as one in the `drawings` directory, since they proxy to the same file.

I'm assuming you wouldn't want to proxy a request for `/pics/first`?

Is it really the intention to match *anything* after `/pics/first/.....`? eg. Would `/pics/first/foo/bar/baz.jpg` be a valid request?

The `L` flag is not strictly required with `P` since it is implied.

---

*Aside:*

> `^/mydir/pics/first(/.*)?`

The trailing `(/.*)?` isn't actually doing anything in this regex, since it's entirely optional. So, the above will match `/mydir/pics/first`, `/mydir/pics/firstanything` and `/mydir/pics/first/anything`. (And the result of the captured group is not used.)

> because of limitations of what can be used in left-hand-side vs.
> right-hand-side of RewriteRule vs RewriteCond (which I still cannot
> understand fully)

You can't use a construct of the form `%{VAR}` (or `%{ENV:VAR}`) inside a regular expression because it conflicts with the syntax of the regex engine (PCRE). There would need to be a pre-process "variable substitution" that occurs before the regex is compiled - but that does not happen.

---

**UPDATE:**

> "You can't use a construct of the form..." - indeed, but I've seen examples where backreferences like `$1`, `%1` or `\1` are used, so I was hoping someone would help me in how could I use those to "propagate" `%{ENV:VAR}` to the regex (if at all possible).

You won't have seen `$1` or `%1` used in the *CondPattern* or `RewriteRule` *pattern* arguments (both *regex* by default), for the same reason as mentioned above. However, you can use `\1` - this is an internal backreference and is part of the regex (PCRE) syntax.

So, as a purely contrived academic exercise, you could do something like the following (extending your example):

```
# Sets SUBDIR env var to one of the allowed subdirectories
# ...but only when that subdirectory is requested
# ...otherwise SUBDIR is "empty"
RewriteRule ^(pics|videos|drawings|songs)(/|$) - [E=SUBDIR:$1]

# Test that one of the stated SUBDIR is present and proxy the request on success
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}@@%{ENV:SUBDIR} ^/mydir/([^/]+)/first(/.*)?@@\1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}@@%{ENV:SUBDIR} ^/mydir/([^/]+)/second(/.*)?@@\1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}@@%{ENV:SUBDIR} ^/mydir/([^/]+)/third(/.*)?@@\1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://192.168.7.13:5055/$2 [P]
```

The same principle applies as with any `RewriteCond` directive. In the case of the first *condition*, you have the *TestString* `%{REQUEST_URI}@@%{ENV:SUBDIR}` that must match the regex `^/mydir/([^/]+)/first(/.*)?@@\1` for the condition to be successful.

The `@@` is just an arbitrary string that does not occur elsewhere in the string to be matched, so we can use it as a *delimiter* between the value of `REQUEST_URI` and `SUBDIR`.

The internal backreference `\1`, at the end of the regex, references the first captured group in the regex. ie. whatever `([^/]+)` matches. And this must match the value of `%{ENV:SUBDIR}` in the *TestString*.

For example, given a request for `/mydir/pics/first/img.jpg` then `SUBDIR` is set to `pics` (the `.htaccess` file is in the `/mydir` subdirectory). So the *TestString* (when expanded) becomes `/mydir/pics/first/img.jpg@@pics`. The `\1` backreference contains `pics` from the second path segment, so this matches the *TestString* `...@@pics` and the condition is successful.

On the other hand, if the request was for `/mydir/foo/first/img.jpg` then `SUBDIR` will not be set (effectively *empty*) and the *TestString* becomes `/mydir/foo/first/img.jpg@@`. However, the backreference `\1` contains `foo` so fails to match the *empty* gap at the end of the *TestString*. ie. `...@@foo` (regex) does not match `...@@` (*TestString*) and the condition fails.

Just to stress, this is a very contrived example, you wouldn't use this method in this case. For instance, the very fact that `SUBDIR` is set at all means that one of the stated subdirectories has been accessed, so the (complex) *conditions* are superfluous. And since the allowed subdirectories are known (and there are only a few) then you might as well just put the regex alternation (ie. `(pics|videos|drawings|songs)`) directly in the rule, as I did in the example at the top of this answer.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite - that clarified a lot. "*Is it really the intention to match anything after*" - yes; in hopes of having a simpler example, I left out that most (all) requests are of the type `/FILENAME.EXT?qsvar1=xx&...`, but I may have inadvertently confused matters more with the naming. "*You can't use a construct of the form...*" - indeed, but I've seen examples where backreferences like `$1`, `%1` or `\1` are used, so I was hoping someone would help me in how could I use those to "propagate" `%{ENV:VAR}` to the regex (if at all possible).

Comment: @sdbbs "requests are of the type `/FILENAME.EXT?qsvar1=xx&...`" - Are you referring to the query string? Note that the above rules only match the URL-path, ie. `/FILENAME.EXT`. The query string, ie. `qsvar1=xx&...` in this example, is not matched and can be anything you like - it is passed through to the target automatically.

Comment: @sdbbs "I've seen examples where backreferences like `$1`, `%1` or `\1` are used" - You can't use Apache backreferences like `$1` and `%1` in the _CondPattern_ or `RewriteRule` _pattern_ for the same reasons as mentioned. However, `\1` is part of the regex syntax so the restrictions do not apply. I've updated my answer with a complete example using internal backreferences to match `SUBDIR`. But note that this is a very contrived/academic example - you don't need to do it this way in this instance.